# i cant run my project, an error like ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx

Tags: android, androidx

I cant run my project. I have an error like "ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx". I am begginer. I try to run my first project but i cannot. From my research i try to add androidx library but i didn't. I dont know what i need to do.

Build grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appco' +
            ',mpat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'


}
```

Comment: see [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx).

Comment: replace "implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appco' +
            ',mpat:1.0.0-beta01'" with "implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'"

Answer (score 0):

**Migrate an existing project using Android Studio**
With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

Here is the official link from android.com 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate